# get the table names from file using UNIX Script

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I am having a sample file as given below. This is an SQL Loader control file:

```
LOAD DATA
APPEND
INTO TABLE XXWIN_TMP_LOADER_TAB
(  seq         POSITION(1:10)  INTEGER EXTERNAL
  ,h_record    POSITION(11:20) CHAR
  ,h_file_name POSITION(21:55) CHAR
)
APPEND
INTO TABLE XXWIN_SQL_LOADER_TAB
(  seq         POSITION(1:10)  INTEGER EXTERNAL
  ,h_record    POSITION(11:20) CHAR
  ,h_file_name POSITION(21:55) CHAR
)
APPEND
INTO TABLE XXWIN_SQL_LOADER_TAB
(  seq         POSITION(1:10)  INTEGER EXTERNAL
  ,h_record    POSITION(11:20) CHAR
  ,h_file_name POSITION(21:55) CHAR
)
```

I would like to select any number of table names occurring in the file which are starting with 'XX_' and ending with '_TAB' and store it into an array using an **UNIX script.**

Please advice.

Thanks,
Arun

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file syntax is not changing (the table names start with `XX`, not `XX_`):

```
tnames=`grep -o "TABLE XX[^ ].*_TAB" <file_name> | sed 's/TABLE //g'`
for tn in $tnames; do echo $tn; done
```

Change the <file_name> to the name of the file.

Comment: Not Working, I wrote it like this:#!/usr/bin/ksh

clear

echo "Test Scripts Running"
echo

tnames=`grep -o "TABLE XX[^ ].*_TAB" DATA_LOADER_CTL.ctl | sed 's/TABLE //g'`

for tn in $tnames; 
 do echo $tn;
done
 This is giving my no output.

Comment: `echo tnames=...` doesn't assign `tnames`. Remove echo. Also, I wrote it for `sh` (`which sh`).

Answer (score 0):

You don't say which shell, but since `sh` doesn't support arrays I'm assuming Bash.

```
tables=($(sed -n '/TABLE /s/TABLE \(XX[^ ]*TAB\) *$/\1/p' inputfile))
for table in ${tables[@]}
do
    echo "$table"
done
```

Comment: Did work out.... #!/usr/bin/ksh

clear

echo "Test Scripts Running"
echo

tables=($(sed -n '/TABLE /s/TABLE \(XX[^ ]*TAB\) *$/\1/p' DATA_LOADER_CTL.ctl))
for table in ${tables[@]}
do
    echo "$table"
done


echo "Done"